# How to get access Leaf Data in p-treeTable?

Tags: angular, primeng

I Have a requiremnt, that to store only leaf Data in DB.
i Have Implimented PrimeNg for Tree Data.
i am able to access all nodes of data, but i am not able to differentiate leafs in that collection.
Please Help me.

```
<p-treeTable [value]="gridData" [columns]="cols1" [(selection)]="selectedNode">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                            {{col.header}}
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
                    <tr>
                        <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
                            <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
                            <p-treeTableCheckbox [value]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0" (click)="managementStructureClick(rowData)"></p-treeTableCheckbox>
                            {{rowData[col.field]}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
                    <div style="text-align: left">
                        Selected Nodes: <span *ngIf="!selectedNode || selectedNode.length === 0" style="font-weight: normal">none</span>
                        <ul *ngIf="selectedNode && selectedNode.length">
                            <li *ngFor="let node of selectedNode">
                                <span style="font-weight: normal">{{'Management Id:'+node.data.managementStructureId + '  Code:' + node.data.code + '  Legal Entity ID:' + node.data.legalEntityId}}</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </p-treeTable>
```

Comment: please correct your tagging. One of them does not apply here

Comment: A leaf is a node without children so just check if the node has children or not.